# Form - Create dynamic textarea for each country checkboxes

Tags: custom-list, form

I have a `custom-list` form with a list of countries:

1. each country is a checkbox.
2. Once the user clicks on the checkbox, a new textarea should appear.
3. I need be able to save this on the custom-list, if the user checked 4 different countries, I need be able to retrieve all 4 textarea individually.

It's possible to do something like this on Sharepoint? What options do I have?

Sharepoint version: 15.0.4905.1000

Comment: Hi Mateus, can you specify the version of SharePoint you are referring to?

Comment: Hi @DenisMolodtsov 15.0.4905.1000 (I'll add on the description). Thanks.

Comment: Oh, another question: do you need all 200+ countries? or you have a much smaller number?

Answer (score 1):

We could do it by using many different approaches, but let's limit them to a couple:

First, start with creating 20 List columns. 10 for the countries and 10 for the respective text boxes. I suggest names like: CountryCanada, DescriptionCanada, CountrySpain, DescriptionSpain etc.

**Approach #1. Add a Content Editor Webpart (CEWP) to the new, edit and display forms**

This is just a simple example that would handle a single country, but you can improve it so that it works with as many as you want:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var canadaCheckBox = $("input[ID^='CountryCanada']");

    var showOrHideField = function() {
        if(canadaCheckBox.is(':checked')) {                
            showField('DescriptionCanada');
        }else{
            hideField('DescriptionCanada');
        }
    };

    // run at startup (for edit form)
    showOrHideField();
    // make sure when the user changes the value - we handle it:
    $(canadaCheckBox).on('change', showOrHideField);

});

function hideField(fieldInternalName) {
    return $("h3#" + fieldInternalName).parent().parent().hide();
}

function showField(fieldInternalName) {
    return $("h3#" + fieldInternalName).parent().parent().show();
}

function getField(fieldInternalName) {
    return $("h3#" + fieldInternalName).parent().parent();
}

</script>
```

**Approach #2. Use AngularJs**

If you know AngularJs - you can use it to create your custom and good looking forms from scratch: `https://github.com/Zerg00s/AngularForms`

You can also try using InfoPath, SPServies or to modify the existing form using SharePoint Designer, but I only like the first two approaches.

Comment: I'm looking for something like option 1, but the problem for me is:

1. The list of countries is checkbox dynamic, so I cannot add static information like "CountryCanada".
2. Later, I'll need recover information about all country descriptions via javascript API. So I will need figure out which description belong to each country.

Thanks for the help.